# Specify view provider type when creating new WinRT view

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Trying to understand the potential use of multiple views in a WinRT app. I can create a new view, which runs on its own dispatcher thread and can be switched in/out, with `CoreApplication.CreateNewView`. I can't figure out how to specify how to pass a view provider in the first argument. If I have a bare app in C# (though the same holds if I use `Application.Start`):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        CoreApplication.Run(new MyViewSource());
    }
}
public class MyViewSource : IFrameworkViewSource
{
    public IFrameworkView CreateView()
    {
        return new MyView();
    }
}
public class MyView : IFrameworkView
{
    // ...
}
```

If I want to create a new view with the current view provider (I suppose the one that created the currently active view), I can do

```
CoreApplication.CreateNewView("", "foo");
```

The API documentation says the 1st parameter is "The class ID of the view provider for the new view." What does that refer to? Anything I tried gave the following:

> Additional information: Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 > >(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: No, though I can't say I spent any more time on it.

Answer (score 1):

First parametr is name of your new view class.

> The class ID of the view provider for the new view. If this parameter is null, use the current view provider.

If you left first parameter null then your new view will have a current view class reperesentation.

So if You want to create a new View with a cutsom class, you have to create this class and put into first parameter.

Like this:

```
public class MySecondView : IFrameworkView
{
// ...
}
```

And then:

```
CoreApplication.CreateNewView("MySecondView", "foo");
```

Let me know about success of this operation becouse I'm not sure about my code.

Comment: Actually if I leave it null it throws an ArgumentNullException (the empty string behaves as per the documentation for null). If I pass it the class name, it gives the class not registered exception as specified in the question. Either the class name is not the ID required (or there's specific syntax), or it needs to be registered somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below for perfect example.

Refernce:
[MSDN Microsoft Multi Windows For An App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn582023.aspx)

Sample Code Example
[Using Multiple Views in Windows Store Apps](http://www.softaware.at/Aktuelles/2014/02/02/Using-Multiple-Views-in-Windows-Store-Apps)